# Good books for relearning high school math from the ground up with complete mathematical rigor and heavy focus on proofs

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, reference-request

I read questions that were similar to mine but I didn't find an answer that was quite what I was looking for.

I want to learn all high school math from the ground up, but I want books that focus extremely heavily on proving every little thing rigorously. Specifically, the topics I would like to study are:

Algebra
Geometry
Trigonometry
Probability and statistics
Pre-calculus and calculus

Even though these topics are usually taught at high school, I'm looking for college level books, since I doubt high school books are as rigorous as I want them to be.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: One of the ones I know about and am going to use is Euclid's Elements, so I am looking for other books like that

Comment: This duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1956640/53259?